# tail command throws errors when used in bash script

Tags: bash, tail

```
for file in swap_pricer swap_id_marks swaption_id_marks
do

    if [ ! -e $file ] && [ "$context" == "INTRADAY" ]
      then
        cp -f $working_dir/brl/$file $file
      else
        tail -n 7 $working_dir/brl/$file >> $file
      fi

      echo "[`date +'%D %T'`] Removing file ${excel_txt_dir}/$file.txt"
      if [ -e ${excel_txt_dir}/${file}.txt ]
      then
        rm -f ${excel_txt_dir}/${file}.txt
      fi
      cp -f ${file}.txt ${excel_txt_dir}/${file}.txt
      cp -f ${file}.txt ${excel_txt_dir}/${file}_${naming_date}.txt
      cp -f ${file}.txt ${file}_${naming_date}.txt
      cp -f ${file}.txt ${excel_txt_dir}/${file}_${naming_date}_${price_time}.txt

done
```

The code above is part of a `bash` script...which has been copied from `csh` script.

I am getting an error:

```
tail: cannot open input
```

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: Try wrapping your path in quotes: `tail +7 "$working_dir/brl/$file"`. Use `set -x` to check that the commands are executing as you expect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You're missing a `do` and a `done`; that complicates the interpretation of your code.  Please show that `working_dir` is set, and the exact code for the loop (or the relevant subset of the exact code for the loop). Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Note that you can indent code by selecting it and using the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  The actual error message is important — I reincluded it from the original version of the question.  Your example is not exactly minimal, but at least it looks like viable `bash`.  You still don't show how `working_dir` is set (which I did request you do).  The problem seems to be that the file you expect to exist (`$working_dir/brl/$file`) does not exist — that is what `tail` is telling you.  Do you have any evidence at all to show why it should be found?  Have you run the script under `bash -x`?

Comment: Not to mention, any time you use a path variable in a script, it should be in double quotes... if its not a problem now, it will be,

Answer (score 0):

In your script, tail is interpreting +7 as a file parameter and complaining that it cant open it.

Try `tail -n 7` instead of `tail +7`

Comment: tpatja now i am getting below usage error-   usage: tail [+/-[n][lbc][f]] [file]
       tail [+/-[n][l][r|f]] [file]

Comment: I'm using tail from GNU coreutils 8.15. The syntax may be slightly different than in your version. You should post your full script.

Comment: for file in swap_pricer swap_id_marks swaption_id_marks swap_reset
   do
      if [ ! -e $file ] && [ "$context" == "INTRADAY" ]
      then
        cp -f $working_dir/brl/$file $file
      else
        tail -n +7 $working_dir/brl/$file >> $file
      fi

Comment: tail (GNU coreutils) 5.97

Comment: Please post your full code in the question, so we can see line-breaks, etc.

Comment: Impossible to help you with the current information. Like Jonathan Leffler suggested, read the instructions on how to create a minimal, complete example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.